# laravel validation to check multi dimensional array

Tags: laravel

I have two fields

```
data[0][student]
data[0][teacher]
data[1][student]
data[1][teacher]
```

I tried this rule
`$rules['data.*.student']  = 'required';`

which gives this error

```
{
    "error": {
        "status_code": 412,
        "validation": {
            "data.student.*": [
                "The data.*.student field is required."
            ]
        },
        "message": "Validation Failed"
    }
}
```

how can I achieve this and make fields required if user missed this input field
`data[student][0]`?

Comment: What is `student`? Your array seems backwards, shouldn't it be `data[0][student]` and `data[1][student]`

Comment: @DigitalDrifter no, i need to do this. ```data[student][0] ```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to validate here?

Comment: It would be usefull to know the html structure of the data you are sending + the values. I think you are on the right track, but missing something

Answer (score 0):

For that you need to set a custom messages for rules inside Formrequest file.

You need to add rules and messages function **Like this demostrated example**:

**Rules**

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'item.*.name' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'item.*.description' => 'sometimes|nullable|string|min:60',
        'sku' => 'required|array',
        'sku.*' => 'sometimes|required|string|regex:​​/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/',
        'sku' => 'required|array',
        'price.*' => 'sometimes|required|numeric'
    ];
}
```

**Message**

```
public function messages()
{
    return [
        'item.*.name.required' => 'You must have an item name.',
        'item.*.name.max' => 'The item name must not surpass 255 characters.',
        'item.*.description.min' => 'The description must have a minimum of 60 characters.',
        'sku.*.regex' => 'The SKU must only have alphanumeric characters.',
        'price.*.numeric' => 'You have invalid characters in the price field.'
    ];
}
```